# Ocultar objetos en reporte con crystalreport

Tags: crystal-reports

Hola estoy creando reportes en crystal reports utilizando java, pero a solicitud de un cliente tengo la necesidad de ocultar ciertos objetos del reporte por decir labels o algun grupo, hay alguna forma de poder ocultar ciertos elementos del reporte o tengo que diseñar otro archivo .rpt que no tenga estos objetos, espero puedan ayudarme con alguna respuesta , gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Debes seleccionar el objeto que quieres ocultar, clic derecho dar formato a objeto y buscar la opción **`suprimir`**:

*Captura de pantalla:*

[image: suprimir]